# Android: AsyncHttpClient reponse goes to OnFailure

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-asynctask

I am trying to parse data from URL. The URL that i test in mobile browser its working fine. I am trying to parse data by **AsyncHttpClient** .after exection its going to **onFailure** method.

in dependencies add

```
   compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

and I import

```
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;
```

..

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                try {
                    pg1.dismiss();
                    String jsonStr = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
                    Log.e("Tag ","jsonStr "+jsonStr);

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                pg1.dismiss();
                Log.e("Tag ","fetch feeds fail");                 
            }
        });
```

The URL is in **GET** method
can any one please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: `Log.e("Tag ","fetch feeds fail");` <= such log is useles ... obviously, you should rather investigate all parameters passed to `onFailure`

Comment: the url is complete, that i am trying to parse, my problem is its not going to onSuccess instead of its calling onFailure. Am get Log in onFailure @ Selvin

Answer (score 0):

Just print responseBody in onFailure() method. if it is timeoutexception; then you can set client.setTimeout(30000); before client.get().

OR

check your url; if  it its giving response in browser or not and also check keys and values. that may be server is not giving you any response.

Comment: on onFailure am getting null as responceBody @Sachin salunkhe

Comment: check your url; if  it its giving response in browser or not and also check keys and values. that may be server is not giving you any response.

Comment: I check with browser and postman plugin there I am getting result, also am getting result in doinBackground() , onPostExecue method. But am not getting result in AsyncHttpClient method @Sachin salunkhe

Comment: then you have to implement all versions of onFailure() method so that you can get exact error or Eception

Answer (score 0):

I am doing same thing using inner class extends AsncyTask.

```
private class JSONWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Weather> {

    @Override
    protected Weather doInBackground(String... params) {

        Weather weather = new Weather();
        data = ((new WeatherHttpClient()).getWeatherData(params[0], params[1]));

        Log.d("DATA", data);

        try {
            weathers = JSONWeatherParser.getWeather(data);

            // Let's retrieve the icon
            weather.iconData = ((new WeatherHttpClient()).getImage(weather.currentCondition.getIcon()));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return weather;

    }
```

inside WeatherHttpClient class I get data using URL with HttpUrlConnection.